# How to retrieve value from a MongoDB collection using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

I am a new user of mongodb database. I have a collection in a mongodb database and I want to retrieve specific value from the collection for a particular field. For example, the mongodb database name is `person` and collection name is `employee` and the records of the `employee` are as follows:

```
Name  Age  Designation  Department
John  39   Manager   Analytics
Dave  28   Scientist Data Science
Mark  48   Analyst   Data Science
Chris 41   Technician Earth Science
Jack  30   Engineer   Visual
```

Now, I want to retrieve just the 3rd value of `Designation` field (that is 3rd value of `Designation` is `Analyst`) and then will display this value (i.e., `Analyst`) to the HTML page. How can we connect mongodb database and retrieve the value using javascript?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are asking here, and it's actually exactly the same as what you posted a few hours earlier. What have you actually tried?

Comment: The question is simple. What will be the script in javascript to connect to the mongodb database and retrieve the value "Analyst" from the mongodb database?

Comment: Trying to help you here. You posted the exact same question a few your ago, and it was heavily downvoted before you deleted it. When I ask you **"What have you tried?"** then instead of telling us how "simple" it is, what you do is "actually show what you tried". "Query from JavaScript" can actually mean many things. Show us what you have actually tried and then we might how some idea how to direct you. As it stands, this question is destined not to be well received. Help us help you by helping yourself.

Answer (score 0):

From your dataset, check following query in mongo shell(javascript):

```
use person

db.employee.find({'Name':'Mark'}, {Designation:1, _id:0})
```